# Apollo Client mutation error and updating components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have the following code which I am trying to decide how to handle errors:

```
const gqlWrapper = graphql(registerMutation, {
    props: ({ mutate, ownProps }) => ({
        registerUser: userDetails => {
            mutate({
                variables: { ...userDetails },
                update: (proxy, resp) => {
                    // perform update to local state based on success
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                // how to update components from here?
            });
        }
    })
});

export default gqlWrapper(Register);
```

The server sends back a GraphQL error object and sends this back so it appears in the `catch()` block of the mutation. If the mutation was successful, the component's data is updated using the `proxy` param, but I can't see an equivalent way of dealing with errors.

Ideally, I'd like to update the Apollo cache in the `catch` block, but I can't even inject props to the component or state at this point either.

The end result would be to set a prop/state on the Register component which shows an error message component with conditional rendering. One way could be to handle the error from where the registerUser mutation originates:

```
// Where the registerUser mutation get's initiated - on form submit
onSubmit={() => {
    this.props.registerUser(values);
    // the error could be caught here but I don't want this in the UI - I'd rather keep all this outside
}}
```

But I feel this adds bulk to the UI which I'd rather have at the bottom of the page, alongside the mutation function. What are the ways around this, or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-link-error with your Apollo client. This would allow you to handle the errors and apply any custom logic you need based on those errors. It should allow you to keep `.catch` out of your components as well. In fact this module is recommended in Apollo's [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/error-handling.html#network)